# Finding Matrix Corresponding to Ellipses of Cost Function

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gradient-descent

For a given cost function $$J(w)=(w-w_0)^TA(w-w_o)$$ it is known that contours of J(w) are ellipses with principal directions have angle of 45° and -45° with the horizontal axis. If eigenvalues of A are $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 1 $.

Based on this we can infer that the major axis of the ellipse is aligned with the horizontal axis, and the minor axis is aligned with the vertical axis? I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ correspond to the lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor axes, respectively.

How can I find out matrix $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$. You should be able to find $\mathbf{A}$ with this information using
$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{U}^T$.
The eigenvectors are the column vectors in the matrix
$$
\mathbf{U}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Each column gives the vector director of the ellipse axes. You are told that the ellipse is rotated by 45° so one director vector of the ellipse is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$ and the second vector is orthogonal to the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please clarify what are the eigenvectors?

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain how did you find out U?